# Why do I get a wrong keyName in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

For instance, I send a request like { "arr": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] } in front-end.Then I get a request.body in Node.js.But the request.body shows as { "arr[]": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }.I can't find out what the wrong it is.I just receive a wrong keyname in my body's ojbect.How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with [`traditional` set to `false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). It is not "wrong"; some frameworks or languages (notably PHP) expect it that way. If you do not, change the parameter to `true`.

Comment: I change the traditional to true,then node log the request with status '400'.I merely use Ajax with its default setting and can't get the meaning of traditional.

Comment: I can't help you with 400 unless you provide a minimal example for both serverside and clientside. But in short, `{ data: [1, 2, 3, 4], traditional: false }` produces `?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3&foo=4`, and `{ data: [1, 2, 3, 4], traditional: true }` produces `?foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3&foo[]=4`.